# How to get RecyclerView to view a certain position WITHOUT scrolling?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently working with a RecyclerView with a custom manager ([found here if interested](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/recyclerplayground/layout/FixedGridLayoutManager.java)). I want to be able to change where the RecyclerView is currently "looking" (ie what position(s) are being displayed). The problem is that when I need to do this, I don't want the user to see the screen scrolling over to the other position, nor do I want to have to load each of those views along the way. So long story short, I need the RecyclerView to change what's being displayed to be positioned around a certain view, and I DO NOT want it to scroll. There is no built-in functionality for this I believe, so I'm hoping someone could give me some guidance. Thank you!

-Dale

Comment: does `public void scrollToPosition(int position)` not work? It is in the code you linked to, and the comments for that function describe exactly the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Ah i did not read the comments on that function. It does seem to, however the name itself is making me skeptical. I will test it out later and reply back here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) both contains `scrollTo` and `smoothScroll` methods, I would think that `scrollTo` would result in a instant jump to the specified position, without scrolling.

**Edited**
Apparently, the direct links did not work. Fixed it. Fairly new here.

Comment: As Zerp said, the custom equivalent of scrollTo is scrollToPosition, but they are conceptually the same I think. Thank you for the answer!